# Wrap datatable pagination control inside a div using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a datatable with pagination. I want to style the `div` containing the `pagination ul`. I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work. I am not able to put the `ul` inside the `div.row` (not able to provide the desired CSS style):

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row myClass">
 <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers" id="grid_paginate">
  <ul class="pagination myUlClass">
    <li class="paginate_button first disabled" aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0" id="grid_first">
      <a href="#" class="paginationFirst"> &lt;&lt; </a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0" id="grid_previous">
      <a href="#" class="paginationPrevious"> &lt; </a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button active" aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0">
      <a href="#" class="">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0">
      <a href="#" class="">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0">
      <a href="#" class="">3</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0" id="grid_next">
      <a href="#" class="paginationNext"> &gt; </a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button last" aria-controls="grid" tabindex="0" id="grid_last">
      <a href="#" class="paginationLast"> &gt;&gt; </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myClass
{
border:1px solid grey;
height:50px;
margin-top:10px;
background-color: #ddd;
}

.myUlClass
{
  float:right;
  z-index:10;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Here is the non-working [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/z53yw5FzXG)

Output which I want looks like [image]

I want pure CSS solution without modifying the HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as simple as setting the following css?

```
.myUlClass {
  border:1px solid grey;
  height:50px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant `.myUlClass` but I guess you do not want to style those but the div surrounding the pagination?

Comment: Both could do, I wanted only CSS solution. Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/VbBlSn6rvK)  problem is you did not reset `margin on ul`  check demo now pagination is in center

Answer (score 1):

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.myClass .paging_full_numbers ul
{
    border:1px solid grey;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top:6px;
}

.myUlClass
{
  float:right;
  z-index:10;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.myUlClass>.active>a{
   background-color: green; 
  }
```